# Json to Pandas, include "Parents"

Tags: python, json, pandas

With a list of 150+ Neighborhoods , I am using Foursquare API to retrieve nearby `venues` at 500m radius of a given Neighbourhood. Each Neighbourhood is expected to return 10-20 nearby `venues`.

Refer to snippet of json result as returned by Foursquare.

With `results['response']['groups'][0]['items']`, I able to retrieve the nearby `venues` information and make it a Table as below. However `results['response']['groups'][0]['items']` does not have the Neighbourhood ( under `headerFullLocation` in json) of  associated `venues`.

****Q: How can I link the Neighbourhood(`headerFullLocation`) to its associated nearby `venue` and add it as a column to table below?** Thanks for the advice.**

[image]

```
{'suggestedFilters': {'header': 'Tap to show:',
  'filters': [{'name': 'Open now', 'key': 'openNow'}]},
 'headerLocation': 'Alexandra Park',
 'headerFullLocation': 'Alexandra Park, Toronto',**
 'headerLocationGranularity': 'neighborhood',
 'totalResults': 138,
 'suggestedBounds': {'ne': {'lat': 43.6545000045, 'lng': -79.39379244047241},
  'sw': {'lat': 43.645499995499996, 'lng': -79.4062075595276}},
 'groups': [{'type': 'Recommended Places',
   'name': 'recommended',
   'items': [{'reasons': {'count': 0,
      'items': [{'summary': 'This spot is popular',
        'type': 'general',
        'reasonName': 'globalInteractionReason'}]},
     'venue': {'id': '5644dbaa498e7f7534154326',
      '**name': 'Maker Pizza',**
      'contact': {},
      'location': {'address': '59 Cameron St',
       'lat': 43.6504011331197,
       'lng': -79.39804047841302,
       'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
         'lat': 43.6504011331197,
         'lng': -79.39804047841302}],
       'distance': 164,
       'postalCode': 'M5T 2H1',
       'cc': 'CA',
       'city': 'Toronto',
       'state': 'ON',
       'country': 'Canada',
       'formattedAddress': ['59 Cameron St', 'Toronto ON M5T 2H1', 'Canada']},
      'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d1ca941735',
        'name': 'Pizza Place',
        'pluralName': 'Pizza Places',
        'shortName': 'Pizza',
        'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/pizza_',
         'suffix': '.png'},
        'primary': True}],
      'verified': False,
      'stats': {'tipCount': 0,
       'usersCount': 0,
       'checkinsCount': 0,
       'visitsCount': 0},
      'beenHere': {'count': 0,
       'lastCheckinExpiredAt': 0,
       'marked': False,
       'unconfirmedCount': 0},
      'photos': {'count': 0, 'groups': []},
      'hereNow': {'count': 0, 'summary': 'Nobody here', 'groups': []}},
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do `venues['Neighbourhood'] = response['headerFullLocation']`. I am assuming, you send a separate request for each neigbhourhood and plan to concatenate multiple venue dataframes in the end.

Comment: So if for the first request I have 20 rows. How do I add the venues['Neighbourhood'] = response['headerFullLocation'] to each of the row? Sorry I am new to programming.

Comment: `df['New Column Name'] = 'This string will be added to each row'`